# Running Ansible tasks (ex: get_url) within a network namespace

Tags: networking, ansible

#### Situation

I have some network gear that must run some commands within a [network namespace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html) in order to reach the internet.

In my scenario, it's the `mgmt` namespace.

For example, to install a pip package, I would do:

```
sudo ip netns exec ns-mgmt pip3 install boto3
```

Or to wget a file, I need to do:

```
sudo ip netns exec ns-mgmt wget https://example.com
```

#### Problem

So, because of this, regular Ansible commands that require reaching the internet do not work:

```
- name: "download file archive"
  get_url:
    url: "{{ my_dl_path }}"
    dest: "/tmp/downloaded_file.tar.gz"
```

#### Solutions / Questions

It seems like I have two options:

- Run the desired commands as a `command` or `shell` task, instead of using individual modules (not best practice).
- Run the tasks on the localhost (using `delegate_to`) and copy the files over. This would be fine for simple things like `wget` instead of [get_url module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/get_url_module.html), but would not work for things like [the pip module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pip_module.html) when installing stuff from the internet.

**How would you tackle this? Is there some sort of Ansible task override to handle this scenario?**

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to run a second sshd daemon inside your netns and connect to it from ansible when you need to run those commands. [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/296064/344536) might be helpful. An other option might be to create a wrapper script that will pass all received argument to /bin/sh and run it inside your netns and then set `ANSIBLE_EXECUTABLE` to that script path in your controller's environment. That second method might not play really well with privilege escalation and will probably require to connect directly as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding

> *Is there some sort of Ansible task override to handle this scenario?*

Yes, there is. Depending on how one look on it, it is quite simple. The solution lays within the [Become plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/become.html).

Regarding

> *How would you tackle this?*

**(1)** You could just create your own customized [become plugin](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/become) based on the existing [`ansible/plugins/become/sudo.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/become/sudo.py), means just tweak it with an additional `'ip netns exec %s' % (become_network_namespace)`.

After a custom become plugin is created and provided, in example called as `sudo_ns.py`, one could use [privilege escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html) and a new to introduce fact `become_network_namespace` like

```yaml
- name: "download file archive"
  become: true
  become_method: sudo_ns
  get_url:
    url: "{{ my_dl_path }}"
    dest: "/tmp/downloaded_file.tar.gz"
  vars:
    become_network_namespace: 'ns-mgmt'
```

**(2)** You could try and test a shortcut with the existing become plugin `sudo` and `become_flags`.

```yaml
- name: "download file archive"
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_flags: 'ip netns exec {{ BECOME_NETWORK_NAMESPACE }}'
  get_url:
    url: "{{ my_dl_path }}"
    dest: "/tmp/downloaded_file.tar.gz"
```

**Further Documentation**

- [Become directives](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#become-directives)